# Is jQuery included in Salesforce Community templates?

Tags: community, napili

Is jQuery included in Salesforce Community templates? I looked for it at "$" and "jQuery" but "$" appears to be some other framework and "jQuery" is undefined.

Perhaps they named it something different?

I'm working specifically with Napili and Koa templates.

My concern is two-fold:

1. Not cause conflicts with any existing jquery version
2. Not to further bloat/slow down the already slow Community site.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice of using jquery with communities would be to use your script in the advanced editor inside Head and not to use any styles and scripts used by SFDC as that may change when we upgrade templates.

Also make sure your jquery is stored inside the static resource of SFDC

[image]

[image]

If you are using inside components use ltng:require tag as below

```
 <ltng:require scripts="/resource/LightningComponentStyles/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>
```

Comment: "when we upgrade templates' - who is 'we' ? is this a secret reveal?

Comment: We here means it can be me ,author of post ,any body building communities with new template. I generally address things with we since I hate words like "I" or you...anyways if this is something I need to correct I will correct it ..

Answer (score 2):

Regardless if jQuery *is* included in a template, you should make no assumptions that this is true, particularly because there are different *versions*, and relying on a magically included version might break in future releases. Instead, you should explicitly import a specific version of jQuery so you make sure your code won't break. There's usually very little overhead if you use a common CDN and link to a specific version, as that will usually cause the code to already be cached if the user visits other sites that use the same jQuery version and CDN.