# JQuery - "$ is not defined" Error only in Experience Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, jquery, libraries

im trying to use jQuery library in my experience builder (LWR) site

i used code from this video: https://youtu.be/W5VLwlXtStM

and it works perfectly OK in salesforce (exactly as shown in video) but in experience builder i'm getting this error:

> {"subject":"app level error","message":"**$ is not defined**","stack":"slideIt@modules/c
> /jqueryDemo.js:1:1146}

Any ideas why this works in salesforce but not in experience builder? thanks

code i used:

JS:

```javascript
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import {loadScript, loadStyle} from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/JQuery'
export default class JqueryDemo extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, jQuery)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('query loaded')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('query not loaded ' + error )
            })
    }

    slideIt(event){
        $(this.template.querySelector('.panel')).slideToggle("slow");
        $(this.template.querySelector('.para')).addClass('important');
    }

    SlideRight(event){
        $(this.template.querySelector('.innerDiv')).animate({left: '275px' });
    }
}
```

HTML :

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Include JQuery in LWC (Lightning Web Component) ">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <div class="flip" onclick={slideIt}>click Here to Slide Down or Up </div>
            <div class="panel">
                <p class="innerDiv" onclick={SlideRight}>JQuery in LWC</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <p class="para">This is paragraph</p>
</template>
```

Comment: possibly helpful - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108733/is-jquery-included-in-salesforce-community-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link from comment by cropredy helped!

adding `<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>` to Head Markup fixed the problem and jQuery library works now

[image: added src to head]